# Unable to use PHP in Apache on Big Sur

Tags: mac, homebrew, apache, php

After using brew to install Apache version 2.4.46 on Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3, and using brew to install PHP 8.0.6, I am unable to run PHP. I am running Apache from /usr/local/etc/httpd, and my Document Root is at /usr/local/var/www. I am not using the Apple supplied Apache.

Here is my phpinfo.php:

```
<?PHP phpinfo(); ?>
```

Here is my phpinfo.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing PHP embedded in HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing PHP embedded in HTML</h1>
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Attempting to access https://myserver/phpinfo.php displays or downloads rather than executing the PHP code. Attempting to access https://myserver/phpinfo.html displays the Title and Heading but not the PHP result.

LoadModule mod_php does not appear (even commented out) in my httpd.conf file.

Everything else appears to work fine.

What do I need to do to enable PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions :

LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so